# Add question's view count to iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, views

The desktop site lists a question's view count on the top right corner of every question page, but I don't see a way to check views on the iOS app or mobile site.

**Can an option be added to view a question's view count on the Stack Exchange iOS app?**